# Tikz-feynman uneven spacing between nodes

Tags: tikz-feynman

Drawing a simple diagram using the tikz-feynman library

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}[large]

\vertex (a) {\(e^{\pm}\)} ;
\vertex[below right=of a] (b);
\vertex[below left=of b] (c) {\(\gamma\)};
\vertex[right =of b] (d);
\vertex[above right=of d] (e) {\(e^{\mp}\)};
\vertex[below right=of d] (f) {\(\gamma\)};
\vertex[below right=1 of c] (l);
\vertex[right =3 of l] (r);

\diagram*{
(a) --  (b) -- [photon] (c);
(b) -- (d);
(e) -- (d) --[photon] (f);
(l) --[<->] (r);

};
\end{feynman}

\end{tikzpicture}    


\end{document}
```

I end up with the the following uneven output

[image]

For example, the top right node is higher than the top left, and the lower left node at the gamma is more to the left than the top right node.
Is there a fix without having to specify explicit positions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that changing the first two vertices to

```
\vertex (b);
\vertex[above left=of b] (a) {\(e^{\pm}\)} ;
```

Does the trick. I don't know why though. Here's how it looks with those switched.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do this. The reason for the unevenness is that the nodes are extended objects. So one can either do the placement symmetrically, or define coordinates, or use the center anchors for positioning.